# Its not giving me the desired output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    printf ("PRN-2301106083");
    int a, b, r;
    char s;
    printf ("\n\nEnter the number 'A':");
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    printf ("\nEnter the number 'B'");
    scanf ("%d",&b);
    printf ("\nEnter the operator '+,-,*,/,%':");
    scanf ("%c", &s);
    
    switch (s)
    {
        case '+':
        printf ("\nYou have entered addition!");
        r=a+b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        case '-':
        printf ("\nYou have entered substraction!");
        r=a-b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        case '*':
        printf ("\nYou have entered multiplication!");
        r=a*b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        case '/':
        printf ("\nYou have entered division!");
        r=a/b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        case '%':
        printf ("\nYou have entered modulus!");
        r=a%b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        default:
        printf ("\nInvalid Choice")
    }
}
```

It will straight away print the last printf's Invalid Choice even when I have not enter the operator from the previous commmand.If anyone can pls send the corrected code or point out what's wrong then pls do.

Comment: Check to see what is in `s`.

Comment: This code doesn't compile because you are missing a `;` after the last `printf` - ergo it cannot have the issue you described

Comment: ==> `scanf (" %c", &s);` notice the space before `%c`

Comment: Its still doing the same thing

Comment: It will still give the Invalid choice output...you can try it in a compiler

Comment: Ok the space did the trick thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%c` conversion specifier won't skip any leading whitespace automatically. One solution to this problem is to put a space before the conversion specifier in the format string, which "tells" `scanf` to skip leading whitespace:

```c
scanf(" %c", &s);
```

Finally, with this fix, your code should look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    printf ("PRN-2301106083");
    int a, b, r;
    char s;
    printf ("\n\nEnter the number 'A':");
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    printf ("\nEnter the number 'B'");
    scanf ("%d",&b);
    printf ("\nEnter the operator '+,-,*,/,%':");
    scanf (" %c", &s);
    
    switch (s)
    {
        case '+':
        printf ("\nYou have entered addition!");
        r=a+b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        case '-':
        printf ("\nYou have entered substraction!");
        r=a-b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        case '*':
        printf ("\nYou have entered multiplication!");
        r=a*b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        case '/':
        printf ("\nYou have entered division!");
        r=a/b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        case '%':
        printf ("\nYou have entered modulus!");
        r=a%b;
        printf ("\nThe output is: %d", r);
        break;
        
        default:
        printf ("\nInvalid Choice");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: you should also check the return value of `scanf`.